# How to execute different commands based on success / failure of previous command in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I need to execute a shell script in (mac os) bash that executes a different command based on whether or not the previous command succeeded.

I tried

```
if ls /Volumes/Shared
    echo success
else
    echo failure
    exit 1
fi
```

but it said "else" in an unrecognized token.

Comment: You're missing the `then` keyword.

Comment: if you don't want to see the output of ls -- you just care about it's return code -- you could redirect it's output to /dev/null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re just missing a `then`:

```
if ls /Volumes/Shared; then
    echo success
else
    echo failure
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: I keep forgetting the ";" before then. Any idea why they required it? The completely missing then was a pasting glitch I didn't catch.

Comment: `if` and `then` are defined as separate commands, followed by “lists” in shell grammar; I don’t know why the shell was built that way initially, perhaps because it makes the constructs easier to parse.